# Project structure for a serverless project

Tags: python, serverless

I'm writing a Python project that will be a serverless with 3 handlers:

- Get partner contacts;
- Get partner deals;
- Get partner flows;

Each handler will be based on date range and for each line retrieved on partner calls, it will save into database.

The macro flow would be something like:

```
                                      -> partner
begin execution -> handler -> service            -> end execution
                                      -> databse
```

Based on that, I have created the following structure:

```
|my-project
    serverless.yaml
    |src
        |handlers (similar to controllers)
        |services
        |infrastructure
            |database
            |partner
    |test
        |handlers (similar to controllers)
        |services
        |infrastructure
            |database
            |partner
```

Does it make sense? And about the partner functions? It's a single partner, should I create a single partner class with those functions or should I create a single python class for each function?

I see a problem creating a single file because every call needs to create a client - it's something like `client = Partner(user, token)`.

I want to make this project looks great but I don't want to write every single stuff that we have on OOP.